# Adding Javadoc of dependencies of a library from Maven in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I want to add a library from Maven, I go to `Project Settings -> Libraries -> New Project Library -> From Maven...` then search for the right library version and tick the `JavaDocs` checkbox. IntelliJ IDEA will download the library, its Javadocs and its dependencies jar files to the repository folder.

Is there any way to also download its dependencies's Javadocs?

Comment: Automatically download Javadoc when adding new maven dependencies: Settings -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> Automatically download -> Documentation

Comment: @luc14n0 I did check the automatically download javadocs but it only downloaded the added library's docs, not its dependencies's.

Comment: Why are you adding dependencies with IntelliJ and not via the Maven POM file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you need to add the library to the POM file instead of using the project settings in IntelliJ and make sure that the following setting is checked:

Settings -> Build -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> Automatically download: Documentation

[image]